# .Net Core 2.0 Web Api: Clean way to call DAL class without needing to instantiate dbcontext in BLL class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core-2.0

I have three assemblies, a Model assembly, a DAL assembly and my BLL assembly.
Now I want to register a user, a controller gets called in my BLL assembly and makes the data ready for a class in the DALL assembly to add the data to de database.

The problem is, in my DAL class I use my dbcontext and the usermanager class from identity. Now when I want to instantiate my DALL class I need to pass the dbcontext and the usermanager, this means I need to instantiate the dbcontext and the usermanager in my controller just to pass them to my DALL class.

So my question is: Is there a clean way to call my DALL class without needing to instantiate data in my controller just to pass it to my DALL class.

**My controller**

```
    public class UserController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser> _passwordHasher;
    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    private ApplicationUserStore _userStore;

    public UserController(ApplicationDbContext _context, IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser> passwordHasher, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _passwordHasher = passwordHasher;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _userStore = new ApplicationUserStore(_context, _userManager);
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("create")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] CreateApplicationUserViewModel model)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            Email = model.Email,
            UserName = model.Email,
            FirstName = model.FirstName,
            LastName = model.LastName
        };
        var result = await _userStore.Create(user);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            try
            {
                _passwordHasher.HashPassword(user, model.ConfirmPassword);
                return Ok();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex);
            }
        }

        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("error", error.Description);

        }
        return BadRequest(result.Errors);
    }
```

**My DALL class**

```
    public class ApplicationUserStore
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public ApplicationUserStore(ApplicationDbContext ctx, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _context = ctx;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task<ApplicationUser> Get(string id)
    {
        return await _context.Users.Where(u => u.Id == id).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    public async Task<IdentityResult> Create(ApplicationUser user)
    {
       return await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
    }

}
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: if it is asp.net core, why are you not using the in-built DI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion.

I had not used dependency injection before but I've figured it out.

What I have done is this,
I have created an interface with the tasks needed in my DAL class like this:

```
public interface IApplicationUserStore
{
    Task<IdentityResult> Create(ApplicationUser user, string password);
    Task<ApplicationUser> Get(string email);
}
```

next I have my DAL class implement the interface like this:

```
    public class ApplicationUserStore : IApplicationUserStore
    {
         private ApplicationDbContext _context;
         private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

         public ApplicationUserStore(ApplicationDbContext ctx, 
         UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
         {
            _context = ctx;
            _userManager = userManager;
         }

         public async Task<ApplicationUser> Get(string email)
         {
             return await _context.Users.Where(u => u.Email == 
             email).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
         }

          public async Task<IdentityResult> Create(ApplicationUser user, 
          string password)
          {
               return await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);
          }

    }
```

I have removed the applicationcontext and usermanager fields from my controller and added the IApplicationUserStore to my controller like this:

```
    public class UserController : Controller
{
    private IApplicationUserStore _userStore;

    public UserController(IApplicationUserStore userStore)
    {
        _userStore = userStore;
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("create")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] CreateApplicationUserViewModel model)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            Email = model.Email,
            UserName = model.Email,
            FirstName = model.FirstName,
            LastName = model.LastName
        };
        var result = await _userStore.Create(user, model.Password);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("error", error.Description);

            }
            return BadRequest(result.Errors);
        }

    }
}
```

and at last added the applicationdbcontext and the IApplicationUserStore to the dependency container like this in my startup class in the BLL.

```
        services.AddScoped<ApplicationDbContext, ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddScoped<IApplicationUserStore, ApplicationUserStore>();
```

In this way my code is loosely coupled and easy to maintain.